# Highlight Excel values

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file (.xlsx) that looks like this:

> ```
>  Col1     Col2    Col3     Col4      Col5     Col6     
>  0.12      N       0.21     Y         0.12     N     
>  0.23      Y       0.1      N         0.14     Y     
>  0.87      N       0.56     Y         0.1      N
> ```

I would like just to have the same .xlsx file with highlighted "Y" for example in red and the corresponding numerical value in the previous column. For example I would like to highlight Y in column 2 and the corresponding numerical value 0.23 in Col1. 
Can anyone help me please?

Best

Comment: What does this have to do with R?  Why not use the Excel conditional formatting?  If you want to do this from R, show what you have tried.

Comment: Conditional Formatting is the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Conditional Formatting did the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll happily delete this if you choose to post your own answer in due course, and assuming your Q is not closed first - somebody seems to think your issue was with "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" (!?) but I'd suggest selecting all six columns and in Format values where this formula is true: under Use a formula to determine which cells to format:

```
 =OR(A1="Y",B1="Y")
```